# if field E contain "MSD__CMT_Change" then

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am not sure if this can be done in SQL Query or not. I can do it EXCEL.
 
**Query**

```
SELECT
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D,
        E,
        F
from TableA
where D in ('MSD_CHANGE','MSD_CMT_CHANGE')
```

[image: sheet]

If field D contains `MSD_CMT_CHANGE` then in row above and right 1 = 7866
another words in excel language E1 = E2.

currently I take query data from SQL and run script in Excel to do it.
if I can do in SQL it would reduce my work load.

**VBA Code:**

```
Sub Test
    Dim rng as Range, cl as Range

    Set rng = Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For each cl in rng
       If cl = "MSD_CMT_CHANGE" AND cl.Offset(-1, 0) = "MSD_CHANGE" Then
           cl.Offset(-1, 1) = cl.Offset(0, 1)
       End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

**Explanation**

```
if field_D = MSD_CMT_CHANGE then  

   compare row above it if equal "MSD_CHANGE" then 

        cell E1 = E2.
```

I have over 5000 rows of data.

Check image below for better explanatation.

Comment: What column are you ordering data by? Is there ID or some other column? Obviously you cannot ordering by D column.

Comment: I am ordering by A. I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean by ID, column A has order#'s in 6 digit number format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assumed that there is a column (in my example that column is `id`) you order data by to get column `D` appeared like this.

```
A    D            
------------------
1 MSD_CHANGE
-----------------
2 MSD_CMT_CHANGE
-----------------
3 MSD_CMT_CHANGE
-----------------
4 MSD_CHANGE
```

In this example ID is a column you order data by

```
select id
      , d
      , decode(d, 'MSD_CHANGE', 
               decode(lead(d, 1, d) over(order by id), 'MSD_CMT_CHANGE', 
                      lead(e, 1, e) over(order by id) , e 
                      ) 
              ,e) e
  from t1
  order by id
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9f75e/1)

Comment: Thanks alot, I know I should've mention in my question before, but how can I look at column A at sametime because it must be for same orderID in column A, don't want it to mix with other orders.

Comment: What do you mean by look at the column A at the same time? Column A(id in this case) is displayed first in the query result.

Comment: meaning column A must have same ID, it is sorted by A, if row1 A <> row2 A, you don't do all this. so if row A3 & A4 have same orderID then all this stuff, `MSD_CHANGE` and `MSD_CMT_CHANGE` must fall under same orderID (columnA)

Comment: You free to sort by whatever column you want, whether it A or any other column, to get values of column D meet you ordering requirements - MSD_CHANGE follows MSD_CMT_CHANGE

Comment: you know how you have in column A `1 2 3 4 5` it should `1 1 2 2 3 3 `  then only compare and replace.

Comment: It was just an example. I have no idea what values in your A column because you didn't tell it. I've assumed that to get the values of column D in that particular order you have to order by some other column not D obviously. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac751/1 -  again this is just an example.

Comment: Thanks it worked, if you can just explain me bit more about decode and lead that would be awesome, it worked but I just used `decode(d, 'MSD_CHANGE',decode(lead(d, 1)` and `lead(e, 1)`

Comment: [Decode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions049.htm#i1017437), [Lead](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions086.htm#i83834)

Comment: got it thanks, decode is like `if else` and `lead` is like offset condition [DECODE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php) and [LEAD](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lead.php)